# Use cleveref package to list three or more chapters

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am using the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) package to refer to chapters in my document with `\documentclass{book}`.

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}\label{ch:first}
\chapter{Second chapter}\label{ch:second}
\chapter{Third chapter}\label{ch:third}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}\label{ch:fourth}
We saw in \cref{ch:first,ch:second,ch:third} that ...
\end{document}
```

For Chapter 4, the MWE yields this:

[image: chapter]

Is there any relatively simple way for `\cref` to instead give the following?

> We saw in Chapters 1, 2, and 3 that ...

Looking at the [`cleveref package manual`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), it seems that `\Crefmultiformat` or `\Crefrangemultiformat` might be appropriate. But if possible, I would like this to apply either only locally or only to chapters. For example, I may indeed want something like "Sections 2.1 to 2.3" for *sections,* just not for *chapters.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are compressing the references by default, but for the chapter references you don't want to do that compression. The solution is to insert an extra comma between (in this case) the last two of your references; this will turn off the compression for that reference list. For a fuller description see §5 of the documentation. If you want the Oxford comma in your references then you'll need to uncomment the `\crefmultiformat` code in the code below.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
%\crefmultiformat{chapter}{Chapters~#2#1#3}{ and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{, and~#2#1#3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}\label{ch:first}
\chapter{Second chapter}\label{ch:second}
\chapter{Third chapter}\label{ch:third}
\chapter{Fourth chapter}\label{ch:fourth}
We saw in \cref{ch:first,ch:second,,ch:third} that ...
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]